# Express proxy server failing when attempting to access over HTTPS

Tags: node.js, express, https

I am trying to setup a proxy server to pass requests made to one server, to another.   I am having a bit of trouble getting this to work on HTTPS.

The server is a VM running Windows Server 2019.

This is my program:

```js
    const fs = require('fs');
    const express = require('express');
    const morgan = require('morgan');
    const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');
    
    const Host = '0.0.0.0';
    const Port = 3000;
    const TargetBaseURL = 'https://myaddressgoeshere.com/';
    
    const sslKey = fs.readFileSync('ssl/key.pem', 'utf8');
    const sslCert = fs.readFileSync('ssl/cert.pem', 'utf8');
    
    const app = express();
    
    app.use(morgan('dev'));
    
    app.use('/proxy', createProxyMiddleware({
        target: TargetBaseURL,
        changeOrigin: true,
        pathRewrite: {
            [`^/proxy`]: '',
        },
        protocol: 'https:',
        secure: true,
        ssl: {
            key: sslKey,
            cert: sslCert
        }
    }));
    
    
    app.listen(Port, Host, () => {
        console.log(`Starting Proxy at ${Host}:${Port}`);
    });
```

I created an self-signed cert by executing the following lines at the Command Prompt:

```
    C:
    cd "C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin"
    openssl genrsa -out cert.key 2048
    openssl req -new -key cert.key -out cert.csr
    openssl x509 -req -days 3650 -in cert.csr -signkey cert.key -out cert.crt
    openssl x509 -in cert.crt -out cert.pem -outform PEM
    openssl rsa -in cert.key -text > key.pem
```

I copied the files that the above steps created to my projects `/ssl` folder.

When I make a request to *http://proxyaddress:3000/proxy/login* , it loads but ultimately fails due to the proxied target's CSP wanting https://

When I make a request to *https://proxyaddress:3000/proxy/login* the program never loads, no request gets written to the console from via the morgan middleware, and  Chrome displays a good old:

> ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

When I run curl, I get...

> curl: (35) LibreSSL/3.3.6: error:1404B42E:SSL routines:ST_CONNECT:tlsv1 alert protocol version

**Can anyone point me in the direction of what I might be able to do to get this working?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up abandoning the use of *http-proxy-middleware* and went with *express-http-proxy* instead.

This is my final, working version of the proxy:

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const https = require('https');
const express = require('express');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const expressHttpProxy = require('express-http-proxy');
const config = require('./config.json');


// Settings
const Host = '0.0.0.0';
const Port = config.Port;
const TargetBaseURL = config.TargetBaseURL;


// SSL
const sslKey = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/ssl/key.pem', 'utf8');
const sslCert = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/ssl/cert.pem', 'utf8');


// Proxy Setup
const proxy = expressHttpProxy(TargetBaseURL, {
    https: true,
    proxyReqPathResolver: (req) => {
        return req.originalUrl;
    },
    userResDecorator: (proxyRes, proxyResData, userReq, userRes) => {
        userRes.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-store');
        let contentType = proxyRes.headers['content-type']; 

        // Set the content-type
        const originalPath = userReq.originalUrl;
        if (originalPath.endsWith('.js')) {
            contentType = 'application/javascript';
        } 
        else if (originalPath.endsWith('.css')) {
            contentType = 'text/css';
        } 
        userRes.setHeader('content-type', contentType);

        return proxyResData;
    },
});


// Express Server
const app = express();
app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use('/', proxy);


// Proxy Middleware
const server = https.createServer({
    key: sslKey,
    cert: sslCert,
    timeout: 60000
}, app);

server.listen(Port, Host, () => {
    console.log(`Starting Proxy at ${Host}:${Port}`);
});
```

Note -- if you utilize this code -- many of the lines in the *userResDecorator* section can likely be omitted as they were specific to my use case.